# Undefined offset and Undefined variable issue

Tags: php, arrays, variables, warnings, undefined-index

Whilst attempting to run the below code, my browser keeps responding with the below errors. How can I fix the below code, so these errors no longer present themselves?

To be clear, these errors appear only on the lines containing each of the below:

> $high = $arr[$middleval+1];
>
> $median = (($low+$high)/2);

Thanks

Code:

```
function median($arr)
{
    sort($arr);
    $count = count($arr); //count the number of values in array
    $middleval = floor(($count-1)/2); // find the middle value, or the lowest middle value
    if ($count % 2) { // odd number, middle is the median
        $median = $arr[$middleval];
    } else { // even number, calculate avg of 2 medians
        $low = $matches[0];
        $high = $arr[$middleval+1];
        $median = (($low+$high)/2);
    }
    return $median;
}
```

Errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in medium.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: matches in medium.php on line 10

Comment: There's no variable `$matches` in the code, I don't see how you could get the second error.

Comment: $low = $matches[0];

Comment: You'll get this error if `$arr` is empty. `$count = 0`, which is even, then you try to access `$arr[0]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: The version I originally posted, was an old version. The correct version is up now. Apologies for that.

Comment: OK, you've never assigned to `$matches`, so what is `$matches[0]` supposed to be?

Comment: Are the line numbers in the errors correct? If line 10 is `$low = $matches[0]`, then line 9 is `} else {`, which can't have `Undefined offset` error.

Answer (score 0):

`Undefined offset` is an out-of-bounds error: you're trying to fetch a value from the array that does not exist. E.g. if your array has two values, at indices `0` and `1`, and `$middleval` equals `1`, `$arr` doesn't have a value at `$middleval + 1`, i.e. `$arr[2]` is not set.

The second error message tells you that you're trying to use a variable `$matches` that is not defined.

You might want to look at [this code review answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223/82053).

Comment: I've edited my code. Apologises